# Integrating Outlook 2010 with Windows Live Messenger for Instant Messaging

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-live-messenger

I've seen a lot of articles about integrating Outlook 2010 with Windows Live Messenger 2011. While this appears to be very easy, I'm running into a problem because the windows live IDs of my contacts are different from our exchange account IDs. For example, my contact is **jsmith@mycompanyexchangeserver.com**, but his live account is **john.smith@live.com**. When I try to "begin a conversation" from within Outlook 2010, Outlook tries to look for a "Windows Live" contact named **jsmith@mycompanyexchangeserver.com** which doesn't exist.

Is there any way to synchronize the two? Ideally I'd like to be able to "associate" **jsmith@mycompanyexchangeserver.com** with **john.smith@live.com** so that I can initiate an IM conversation from within Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Contact details in Outlook, there is a field for `IM Address`.  Use that for the Windows Live Messenger Live IDs.

It would be easier if you were all using Office Communicator 2007 or Lync 2010.

Comment: I'll try that right now, thanks! And yes, my organization is working on deploying Office Communicator/Lync but it's nothing I have control over. We need a solution to use in the mean time ;-)

Comment: @Pandincus: Did it work?

Comment: It does, but unfortunately it requires manually copying each person to my local contacts, and it requires that they first 'friend' me using their live account. This is to be expected, I just wish there was a magic solution ;-) Thank you!